# UIView behind UIWebView prevent Scrolling over the UIWebView content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiwebview, scroll

I have `UIView` i set it's Alpha to Zero to animate it to be hidden, and i bring a new view which is `UIWebView` when i try to scroll the content of the `UIWebView` the hidden UIView is preventing the `UIWebView` to scroll, Is there anyway to bring the `UIWebView` to front with out letting the Behind view preventing the scroll process?

---

#### Code: after "Oleg Danu" Answer

```
 [self.ParentView.view sendSubviewToBack:self.ParentView.UITableView]; 

 [self.ParentView.view bringSubviewToFront:self.WebView];
```

I am still unable to scroll the UIWebView Contents.

Comment: ParentView is a UIViewController? What is self.ParentView.table?

Comment: @Oleg Danu: The self.ParentView.table is UITableView sub-viewed with the UIViewController, Do you think that is a problem?

Comment: Well it should actually work, if ParentView.view has as subviews a TableView and a WebView.

Comment: Anyway i am so appreciated for following up with me, i will try to change my design pattern, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand both of your views are subviews of some any other view. In this case try next:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:myFrontWebView];
```

or

```
[parentView sendSubviewToBack:myBackHiddenWebView];
```

Comment: it did not work, i will update my Question right now to show you exactly what i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the webview which you do'nt want to be seen.

```
myWebView.hidden = YES;
```

OR

```
if(isShowFirstWebView)
{
  [self.view addSubViews myFirstWebView];
  [mySecondWebView removeFromSuperView];
}
else 
{
  [self.view addSubViews mySecondWebView];
  [myFirstWebView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i am afraid the result is still the same.

Comment: Lets say we have myUIWebView1 & myUIWebView2 as UIWebView views                    if(Put your condition here)  {   Remove myUIWebView1 from super view ; Add  myUIWebView2 as subView }else{ Remove myUIWebView2 from super view ; Add  myUIWebView1 as subView} and do'nt use myWebView.hidden = YES;

Comment: i can't remove the "Is going to be hidden view" because i need to view it again when the user finish viewing the data on the UIWebView.